# plotly dash callback return dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, callback, plotly-dash

I am using plotly dash in order to drag and drop a file in, and then produce a series of graphs controlled by a slider. I am struggling to get the callbacks for this to work in an efficient way.

I want to return the dataframe from the file upload and then use this in the graph function. But I couldn't get this to work. Below is the code I've written so far:

```py
    app = Dash(__name__)
    
    app.layout = html.Div(
        children=[
        dcc.Upload(
            id='upload-data', ...),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
        dcc.Slider(id='slider-datetime', ...),
        html.Div(id='updatemode-output-container', style={'margin-top': 20, 'font-family':'arial'},
        html.Div(id='output-data-upload') )
    ])
    @app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
                  Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
                  State('upload-data', 'filename'),
                  State('upload-data', 'last_modified'))
    def parse_contents(contents, filename,date):
        data = read_data_file(filename, ...)
        return data
    @callback(
        Output('graph', 'figure'),
        Input('upload-data', 'filename'),
        Input('slider-datetime', 'value'), prevent_initial_call=True
    )
    def update_graph(children,value):
        dtchosen = unixToDatetime(value)
        dff = children.loc[dtchosen]
        fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3)
    
        fig.add_trace(row=1, col=1,
            trace=go.Scatter(x=data.x, y=data.y))
        return fig
```

I have managed to take the filename into the graph function with the slider and output and then load the data and plot. However this is really slow as it loads the data everytime the slider is moved.

```py
    app = Dash(__name__)
    
    app.layout = html.Div(
        children=[
        dcc.Upload(
            id='upload-data', ...),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
        dcc.Slider(id='slider-datetime', ...),
        html.Div(id='updatemode-output-container', style={'margin-top': 20, 'font-family':'arial'})
    ])
    @callback(
        Output('graph', 'figure'),
        Input('upload-data', 'filename'),
        Input('slider-datetime', 'value'), prevent_initial_call=True
    )
    def update_graph(filename,value):
        data = read_data_file(filename, ...)
        dtchosen = unixToDatetime(value)
        dff = data.loc[dtchosen]
        fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3)
    
        fig.add_trace(row=1, col=1,
            trace=go.Scatter(x=dff.x, y=dff.y))
        return fig
```

Is it possible to return the dataframe from the upload? Or is there generally a more efficient way of doing this?

I also tried returning dataframe from the function taking the upload file name from the callback, but this didn't work.

Comment: Please, add part of your code.

Comment: Thank you @JIST I have now updated to include code